# How to Sort ListView Items by Date

Tags: android, sorting, date, listview

In my application i have to show an list view which shows Date and an String value.An Model class is used for providing values to Array list. Date.Date value is derived using an value from the Model class at the Adapter Class.Have to show the list view sorted by the date in ascending order and highlight the view which is closest to the current date.highlight in the sense of change the background color of particular view which is next greater to or equal to the current date.

BaseAdapter Class

```
 private ArrayList<Model> mListItems;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Integer[] mListIcons;
    private Date DateOfBirth;
    private int NumberOfMonths;
    private ArrayList<Integer> SottList;
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();

    public Adapter(Activity mActivity, Date DateOfBirth,ArrayList<VaccinationScheduleModel> mListItems) {
//        super();

        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mListItems=mListItems;
        this.DateOfBirth=DateOfBirth;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_lv_vacc_schedule,
                    parent, false);
        } else {
            convertView = convertView;
        }

       String  atrNumberOfMonths=mListItems.get(position).getmNumberOfMonths();
        NumberOfMonths = Integer.parseInt(atrNumberOfMonths);
        Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(DateOfBirth);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, NumberOfMonths);
        Date result = cal.getTime();
        dateList.add(result);
        String dayOfTheWeek = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", result);//Thursday
        String stringMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", result); //Jun
        String intMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM", result); //06
        String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", result); //2013
        String day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", result); //20
        System.out.println("19102015:VaccinationScheduleAdapter" + result);
        TextView txtVaccTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccTitle);
        TextView txtVaccMonth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccMonth);
        TextView txtVaccDay= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccDay);
        TextView txtVaccYear = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccYear);
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_icon);
        txtVaccTitle.setText(mListItems.get(position).getmDescription());
        txtVaccMonth.setText(stringMonth);
        txtVaccDay.setText(day);
        txtVaccYear.setText(year);
        Collections.sort(dateList);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {




            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Can Any one help me?Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you are fetching data from database then make query for that

Comment: I am not using database

Comment: what are you using?

from where are you getting the dates?

Comment: On constructor calling i will send an Date.By using that date as base other dates are derived

Comment: your dateList make me confused. which list you want to sort..mListItem or dateList

Answer (score 6):

Where you call your adapter Class use:

```
Collections.sort(mListItems, new CustomComparator()); 
adapter = new YourAdater(this,dateOfBirth, mListItems);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Your CustomComparator may look like this:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<YourObject> {// may be it would be Model
    @Override
    public int compare(YourObject obj1, YourObject obj2) {
        return obj1.getDate().compareTo(obj2.getDate());// compare two objects
    }
}
```

For highlighting your first one or two rows, write this code inside your adapter's getView method. No need to sort anything here.

```
if(position==0){ // for two rows if(position==0 || position==1)
   convertView.setBackgroudColor(Your Color);
}
```

Hope it helps you.
If you face any problem, just comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only with sorting a list, you can use a `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(mListItems, new MyComparator<Model>() {
    int compare(Model first, Model second)  {
        return first.getDate().compareTo(second.getDate());
    }
});
```

It would be helpful if you post the code used to get the items list and your `Model` class.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `Collections.sort(dateList)` on `getView` is totally wrong, you should generate a sort method on your adapter and use it outside the adapter (maybe on the fragment onStart or onResume) make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter right after.

Answer (score 0):

This video help me a lot to sort by date:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTGtk1AuQCI

It is about how to sort but with `for` statements.

I first have an `arrayList` of `claseRenta` items and each of them contain the date in a `String`. I first convert the string into a date and after I get the time in millis, after that I compare the time in millis and rearrange the `arrayRentas`. At the end I obtain an array of `claseRenta` items sorted by the date of each one.

```
public void sortRentas() {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM, yyyy  hh:mm a");

    for(int i=0; i<arrayRentas.size();i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<arrayRentas.size(); j++){
            Date date1 = null;
            try {
                date1 = format.parse(arrayRentas.get(i).getFechaEntrega());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            calendario.setTime(date1);
            millitime1 = calendario.getTimeInMillis();
            Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = format.parse(arrayRentas.get(j).getFechaEntrega());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            calendario.setTime(date2);
            millitime2 = calendario.getTimeInMillis();

            if(millitime1>millitime2){

                temporalRenta = arrayRentas.get(i);
                arrayRentas.set(i,arrayRentas.get(j));
                arrayRentas.set(j,temporalRenta);

            }

        }
    }
```